# How to parse json response for ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, json

I am newbie to ajax/javascript. I am trying to parse response for below ajax request:

```
function invokeMediationRestService(rql) {

var resourceinfo;
var request = $
        .ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "REST_URL",
            async : false,
            data : 'SOME_DATA',
            contentType : "application/xml",
            dataType : "xml",
            success: function(response) {

            }
    });

return resourceinfo;
```

}

For this request I am expecting response like below: 
JSON:

{
  "xml-fragment": {
    "@payloadMode": "JSON",
    "serializedPayload": "{\"items\":[{\"$param\":\"Response\",\"mode\":\"OUT\",\"$value\":[{\"resource\":[{\"firstName\":\"abc\",\"email\":\"abc2.klm@xyz.com\",\"alias\":\"cklm28\",\"manager\":\"vbu\",\"location\":\"qwerty\",\"department\":\"asdfg\",\"lastName\":\"klm\",\"displayName\":\"klm, abc\",\"containerID\":\"456\",\"containerName\":\"sfdghjjk\",\"groupID\":{\"guid\":\"23454356wert\",\"name\":\"qweryugg\",\"label\":\"asdfgfdg\",\"$type\":\"sdfgdsf\"},\"$type\":\"sdfgsdfg\"},{\"firstName\":\"abc\",\"email\":\"abc3.klm@xyz.com\",\"alias\":\"cklm29\",\"manager\":\"sdfgrt\",\"location\":\"qwerty\",\"department\":\"sdfghj\",\"lastName\":\"klm\",\"displayName\":\"klm, abc (zxa2)\",\"containerID\":\"456\",\"containerName\":\"sfdghjjk\",\"groupID\":{\"guid\":\"23454356wert\",\"name\":\"qweryugg\",\"label\":\"dfgh\",\"$type\":\"dghdh\"},\"$type\":\"dfghgfh\"}]},{\"$param\":\"dfghj\",\"$value\":[\"sdfghj\"],\"type\":\"String\",\"mode\":\"IN\"}]}"
  }
}

Please note: There are multiple records under "items[0].$value[0].resource".
I want to extract these records and return them.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks,
Ranjeet

Comment: No need to parse when used `dataType : "json"` in `$.ajax` configuration options.

Comment: You should be able to get the JSON string by doing something like $(response).find("serializedPayload").text(), and then parsing the JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll probably be a little trial and error - I get a bit confused with JSON at times and forget which sections are arrays and which are just readable.

When I've been dealing with JSON before I use

```
var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

to get the parsed object. You can then access key/value pairs with something like `json.items`. If there can be multiple items I think you would want something like `json.items[0].$value[0].resource[0].name` to read from the right section, but depending on how flexible the layout of your JSON response is you might need to specify the index (using `[index]`) at other points.